# Class org.kie.pmml.pmml_4_2.osgi.Activator not found in the project - jbpm custom task using kie-server-client dependency

Tags: jbpm, kie-server

I've created a custom task to query data from kie execution server using kie-server-client java api. I've added kie-server-client dependency in my custom work item handler pom.xml file. I can successfully build the project and use as a custom work item in jbpm workbench. The problem is when I deploy the project it is showing the class not found error as below. Can someone help me solve this problem. Thanks!

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
  <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.kie.server</groupId>
  <artifactId>kie-server-client</artifactId>
  <version>7.61.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1cEG.png)

I've tried with different version for both jbpm and kie java api. It didn't work.

```
1: Error when creating container test_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT by extension jBPM KIE Server extension due to Class org.kie.pmml.pmml_4_2.osgi.Activator not found in the project
```